# Do Hoffman and Kunze seem to forgo easy "if and only if" statements?

Tags: reference-request, soft-question

For those who have read Hoffman and Kunze, am I imagining that they seem to have this really bad habit of stating "one-way" implications when it is literally no more work to state (and show) the "if and only if"? This shouldn't matter too much, except that as theorems get harder it might be more and more difficult for the reader (i.e. me) to detect when a statement is generalizable to an equivalence.

As an example, Corollary 3 on page 46 reads

> Let $A$ be an $n \times n$ matrix over a field $F$, and suppose the row vectors of $A$ form a linearly independent set of vectors in $F^n$. Then $A$ is invertible.

The converse is much more immediate than the direction given here, so why don't HK state it?! Just trying to get a sense if people consider this a weakness of this classic, or if I am imagining that this is happening with greater regularity than usual.

Comment: I agree it can be annoying when one side of the implication is obvious, but they don’t even bother saying it is obvious/elementary. But, yes it is somewhat common for some texts to state only the non-trivial implication (I don’t have experience with HK specifically). But, I think while this can be annoying, it is a good thing for students to **stop** and think about things (I’ve benefitted greatly). One of the best basic questions a student can ask and think about are “is the converse true” and “what if I drop this hypothesis” and  “can I in fact make the stronger conclusion that___”.

Comment: Sometimes, you can have a theorem which is actually an if and only if, where one direction follows almost immediately, but the other takes literally pages of effort. So in this case, mentioning the trivial direction just seems distracting (and I think it’s entirely reasonable to let the reader figure out which is the important part).

Comment: All of the above is well taken, thank you :) @peek-a-boo